# Conditional Formatting Time After Midnight in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a Google Sheets timesheet. I want to conditionally format a cell if the user enters a Time Out past Midnight. In the example below, the user added an extra 15 minutes to his Time Out, which belongs on the row for the next day.
[timesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crwhZ.jpg)
I tried Conditionally Formatting a cell for any time greater than Midnight, which didn't work because ALL times are beyond Midnight. Also, I want to apply the conditional formatting to every cell in my Time Out columns. So I'm guessing the solution must involve the ARRAY function.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually what you have here is a conceptional issue instead of formula problem. As you have say, ```ALL times are beyond Midnight.```, so it won’t work if you try to do something when the input time is beyond Midnight. You have to first figure out a logic that should work, applying the logic to your project with formulas is only the next thing.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you need to highlight those timelines that start in one day and finish in the next one, you can think that the condition will be true if the hour of leaving is smaller than the hour of arriving (unless you can have more than 24 hours straight, in which case this wouldn't work).

Then you could set this condition:

> =if(hour($C2)<hour($B2),true,false)

[image]

Comment: Martin's solution is nearly perfect. But it's conditionally formatting "12:00 AM". I want the conditional formatting to display with values beginning at "12:01 AM". How do I add a minute to the formula?

Comment: =if(hour($C2)<hour($B2),if(and(hour($C2)=0, minute($C2)=0),false,true),false)

Comment: @user194678 try this!